# Sharepoint 2013 Value does not within expected range

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have sp2013 production environment where sometimes not always, this error comes up
"Value does not fall within expected range".
The error apparently is thrown from below code which queries list.but code is alright as it works all right sometimes but breaks other times..

```
 var incompleteJobs = from queue in testlist
                                     where(2conditions here)                                            
                                     select queue;
```

ignore any syntax error , but basically code retrieves data from sharepoint list

Comment: You better add some log handling on exception in order to see what value has the problem. I faced this before when calling lists.asmx.

Comment: what was the cause? as it's random behaviour and hence probably not with code.

Comment: When i was asking the lists.asmx to update some field, the <FieldRef Name="ID" /> was wrong , mean i was sending quid and wanted int. But that was my case... That's why i told to add some logging.